# SQL join or subselect total combined matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables that named as:

- user
- userAccount
- userRight

with 1 to many relationship.

What I'm looking for is a query that will give me the total number of accounts & rights.

For example:

```
user: a
account: 1, 2, 3
right: a, b, c

user b
account: 1, 2
right: 

user c:
account: 1
right: e, f, g, h
```

should return result ordered by count in a descending order

```
a 6
c 5
b 2
```

I had it close using joins and grouping, but I end up getting a: 9 as its getting 3 x 3 records.

Comment: put your table schema here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try following one

```
SELECT user_name,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userRight WHERE user_id=u.user_id) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userAccount WHERE user_id=u.user_id) AS total 
FROM user u ORDER BY total DESC
```

if you want to user total into where clause then

```
SELECT user_name,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userRight WHERE user_id=u.user_id) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userAccount WHERE user_id=u.user_id) AS total 
FROM user u WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userRight WHERE user_id=u.user_id) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userAccount WHERE user_id=u.user_id))>10 ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, that works and I hadn't tried sub selects, is there a non sub select way or are they no longer considered bad.

Comment: Also with a subselect approach how can I then put that total in a where clause.

Comment: I need to say something like where total > 10 but total doesn't seem to exist to the where clause.

Comment: @DaleFraser, Here total is dynamic column, so you can't use into Where clause. i have add one query which run for where clause. Hope it will help you

Comment: Yep I figured I needed to do the query again in the where, thanks